# Jquery onchange alternative that works with auto fill form plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the JavaScript onChange to work with a [autofill](http://autofillforms.mozdev.org/drupal/content/main-page) form extension. The problem is that when you click the button to autofill the form it doesn't call the onChange. Is thre a work around for this?

Example HTML:

```
<select onchange="$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?country_id=' + this.value + '&amp;zone_id=');" name="country_id">
      <option value="false"> --- Please Select --- </option>
      <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="2">Albania</option>
      <option value="3">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What about if you assign the `change` event handler to the `select` element in a separate javascript code or file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, though with input fields rather than select. The browser form autofill feature doesn't fire any js events as far as I could see, so I ended up using `setInterval` to periodically validate the fields.